# Что делать, чтоб PHP файлы работали?

Tags: php

Хотел разобраться с РНР. Скачал учебник. Написал Код:

```
<html>
<title><? print "Hello world!"; ?></title>
</html>
```

В мозилле выдает заголовок `<? print "Hello world!"; ?>`, но надо "`Hello world!`". Не видит РНР. Дальше прочел, что РНР серверный язык, и надо сервер "включить". Скачал ХАМР, но он не запустился. Скачал денвер, установил денвер, РНР на денвер, работает но ничего не происходит, когда включаю.

Что делать?

Comment: начать мануалы читать внимательнее + на сайте денвера есть много разделов помощь.

Comment: Возможно просто сервер на настроен на поддержку коротких php тегов. Попробуйте вместо `<?` сделать `<?php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте писать PHP код в файле с расширением *.php - все получится!

Comment: С расширением `*.php` и `htm`l не работает, мне кажется, что он в html тоже должен работать, дело не в этом.

Comment: Вы апач запустить не забыли?

Comment: ХЗ,запущен

Answer (score 1):

Файл должен быть с расширением .php

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете тренироваться в PHP без веб-сервера. Для этого достаточно (на примере Linux) вызывать код из скрипта

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
    var_dump($argv);
?>
```

и запуск на исполнение

```
chmod +x test && ./test
```

Если скрипт запускается из под веб-сервера, то надо убедиться в том, что

1. веб-сервер с поддержкой PHP запущен
2. скрипт лежит там, где положено (корневая папка веб-сервера)
3. в браузере открыта правильная страница (`http://127.0.0.1/hello.php` и т.п.)

Comment: пункт 2 и 3 не исполнен)

Answer (score 0):

Действительно с расширением HTML не работает такой вариант, с расширением PHP работает!